# How to skip None entries in px.treemap

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python

Here is my data:

[image]

I want to plot a tree map plot with plotly express that looks like this:

[image]

But currently using this code:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Product': ['Auto', 'Auto', 'Auto', 'Auto', 'PP', 'PP'],
        'New': ['No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', None, None],
        'Category': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
        'Count': [1003, 307, 44, 65, 3814, 3095],
        'Price': [1872.1, 6753.2, 7380.4, 7673.4, 2951.9, 2447.25]
    }
)
fig = px.treemap(
    test_df,
    path=[px.Constant('Group'), 'Product', 'New', 'Category'],
    values='Price',
    hover_data=['Count'],
    color='Price',
    color_continuous_scale='RdBu'
)
fig.show()
```

I'm getting the error

> 'None entries cannot have not-None children'

and when replacing `None` with a white-space string `" "` I'm now getting an additional group:
[image]

How can I get rid of that additional group ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is (which I don't recommend) :

```py
test_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Product': ['Auto', 'Auto', 'Auto', 'Auto', 'PP', 'PP'],
        'New': ['No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'A', 'B'],
        'Category': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', None, None],
        'Count': [1003, 307, 44, 65, 3814, 3095],
        'Price': [1872.1, 6753.2, 7380.4, 7673.4, 2951.9, 2447.25]
    }
)
```

It produces what you want but it is problematic as it could mislead the user, maybe not in this specific case because 'New' would only have value Yes|No and is only one level above the category, but in general users would expect having regions for the same level to be displayed at the same level of nesting.

The path is `px.Constant('Group'), 'Product', 'New', 'Category'`, so if the product 'PP' has no value for 'New', you should use [`N/A`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N/A) (or equivalent) and set its category at the category level so that the representation and the interactions remain consistent :

```py
test_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Product': ['Auto', 'Auto', 'Auto', 'Auto', 'PP', 'PP'],
        'New': ['No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'N/A', 'N/A'],
        'Category': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
        'Count': [1003, 307, 44, 65, 3814, 3095],
        'Price': [1872.1, 6753.2, 7380.4, 7673.4, 2951.9, 2447.25]
    }
)
```